# Mercurial: List all unmerged branches

Tags: mercurial

How do I list all unmerged branches?

That is, I want a list of all branches that are not closed, and their head is not merged into some other branch.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the [branches command](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Branch#Named_branches)

> hg branches --active

Branches are considered active if their last commit has not been merged into another branch. Closed branches won't appear in the output at all.

If you need to handle the list programmatically, and can use .NET, there is also a [Mercurial .NET](https://mercurialnet.codeplex.com/) library that can make this easy.

Comment: Word of warning - this option is deprecated in Hg 3.3.

Answer (score 5):

According to http://bugs.python.org/issue15917 this should work:

`hg log -r "head()-parents(merge())-closed()-tag(tip)" --template "{branch}\n"`

The corresponding TortoiseHg filter is

`head() and not closed() and not parents(merge()) and not tag(tip)`

Comment: for properly merged repository you'll always get `tip` as result and tip's branch. Add `-tag(tip)` to revset

Comment: I had more success with the following revset: `head()-ancestors(closed())-ancestors(head()~1)-secret()` this also filters branches which simply where renamed