# Subversion: How to get a list of all active, unmerged branches

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, branch

My question is similar to [Mercurial: List all unmerged branches](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26248797/534406) but for SVN, not Mercurial.

I need to find a way to list all currently open branches that haven't been merged into mine (usually trunk).

As far as I'm aware, the equivalent feature in Git is `git branch --no-merged` and `git branch --merged`

For clarification, I'm *not* asking for a list of unmerged *revisions*, like many other StackOverflow questions have asked in the past.

I'll accept any solution that is able to to list all **active** branches that are not yet merged. If this isn't possible, then I will accept an answer that lists all active, *merged* branches, allowing me to work backwards.

For example, if I'm on `repo/trunk`, and the repo has these branches:

- `repo/branches/b1` has not been merged into trunk
- `repo/branches/b2` has been merged
- `repo/branches/b3` was deleted in a previous revision and wasn't merged
- `repo/branches/b4` was deleted after being merged

Your solution should return either b1 or b2, but must never return b3 or b4.

Comment: Can you define what makes a branch "active" in your scenario?  Recent commits? At least one commit since it was branched?

Comment: @PatrickQuirk A branch can be considered active if it is present in the HEAD revision.

Comment: Did you try to create a script/ batch that list all directories in `repo/branches/` and then check for each of them with `svn mergeinfo` if there is anything that needs to be merged?

Comment: @royalTS A custom script is something I thought to be possible, but it's way beyond my capabilities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you have to take list all branches in the HEAD revision:

```
svn list repo/branches/ -r HEAD
```

And then, you have to loop through results, and check mergeinfo. Here is a script that you can save as *.bat file:

```
@echo off

for /f %%b in ('svn list repo/branches -r HEAD') do call :revisions %%b

exit /b

:revisions
for /f %%r in ('svn mergeinfo --show-revs eligible repo/branches/%1 repo/trunk') do (
    echo repo/branches/%1
    exit /b
)
```

I'm using a **:revision** subroutine here, because I want to exit it when I see the first revision available to merge. That's why this program won't print duplicate branches.

Comment: Your command will indeed show all branches in HEAD. That's quite simple to do. However, that's not what I need. I only want to see a subset of those branches that haven't been merged into trunk.

Comment: My bad. I fixed my solution.

Comment: Nicely done! I've tested this on our old SVN repo by creating a new branch (which appears in the list) and then merging it into trunk (causing it to drop off the list). Keep answering like that and you'll have plenty of rep in no time. :)

Comment: FYI I adapted the batch file to add `set repo=https://...` and then replaced `repo` with `%repo%` throughout to make it reusable. You might want to update your answer to make it easier for others.

Answer (score 1):

For those people using MacOS or Linux, here is a simple bash script based on [Peska's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47885629/69231). You can pass paths to the branch and trunk folders on the command line, or it will default to the default remote paths ^/branches and ^/trunk

```sh
#!/bin/bash

BRANCHDIR=${1:-^/branches}
TRUNKDIR=${2:-^/trunk}

for branch in $(svn list "$BRANCHDIR" -r HEAD)
do
    for revision in $(svn mergeinfo --show-revs eligible "$BRANCHDIR/$branch" "$TRUNKDIR")
    do
        echo "$BRANCHDIR/$branch"
        break
    done
done
```